# difference between ctor{} and {} when returning non-movable, non-copyable object

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is the situation I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    test() { cout << "ctor" << endl; }

    test(const test&) = delete;
    test(test&&)      = delete;
};

auto f() -> test {
    return {};
    // return test{};
}

auto main() -> int {
    f();
}
```

This code compiles with both clang and gcc, but when I change `return {}` to `return test{}` it doesn't compile anymore. Why is that? Shouldn't it work the same in both cases?
Frankly, I don't know if there is a good use case for this, but it caught me by surprise, so now I'm wondering what's going on.

Comment: you realize that's just the default constructor right

Comment: When did C++ become another language?

Comment: @Havenard: The early 1980s. Or are you asking about the newish features from 2011?

Comment: Must be this C++11, they introduced some crap completely alien to C++. I don't even understand whats {} good for other than declaring arrays and structuring blocks of code. This synthax above is some serious nonsense to me.

Comment: Anyway why using `auto main() -> int` instead of `int main()` if `int` is a primitive?

Comment: @Havenard For consistency's sake.

Comment: @Havenard ...also, when I started using `auto` a lot, I started to pay much more attention to names than to types, so to me it makes sense to put the name before the type.

Comment: @Havenard: The `{}` is *brace initialisation*, which gives a more flexible and uniform way of initialising objects than was historically possible. For example, as we see here, you can initialise the return value directly rather than creating a temporary to copy. There's a decent article about it [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c19081/C-2011-Uniform-Initialization.htm), if you want to know more. For more C++11 stuff, see [Stroustrup's tour](http://isocpp.org/tour).

Comment: Thanks, I was searching Google for insights on this but unfortunately Google ignores brackets and gives me unrelated results.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`return {}` uses an empty initialiser list to initialise the return value, using the default constructor.

`return test{}` creates a temporary using the default constructor, then uses that to initialise the return value using a move or copy constructor. You have deleted those constructors, so that can't be done.

In practice, the copy or move will be elided so that both have the same effect - but the second still requires an accessible constructor, even if it's not actually used.

Comment: Note: Both versions are legal since C++17, there is no longer a conceptual temporary  in between the return expression and the result object

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of Mike's answer:

```
int main()
{
    // Error: Call to deleted move constructor (in C++98 the compiler would 
    // shout at the private copy constructor).
    // auto t = test{};

    // OK: Default constructor used
    test t2;
    test t3{};

    return 0;
}
```

Even though the move/copy is elided, the C++ standard requires visibility of these constructors.